# addView() doesn't show the view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm using addView() to add an inflated layout from XML to LinearLayout.
but it doesn't show it!

```
 DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(getContext());
    int tabCount = category_tabs.getTabCount();
    if (tabCount > 0) {
        TabLayout.Tab tabAt = category_tabs.getTabAt(0);
        Category category = (Category) tabAt.getTag();
        int category_id = category.getId();
        Request filesRequest = dataAccess.getFiles(category_id, book.getId());
        dataAccess.callRequest(filesRequest, new ResponsRun() {
            @Override
            public void run(Response response) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    if (result.getBoolean("result")) {
                        File[] files = gson.fromJson(result.getJSONArray("data").toString(), File[].class);
                        for (File file : files) {
                            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                            View file_card = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.file_card, null);
                            TextView filename = file_card.findViewById(R.id.filename);
                            ImageView bookmark_img = file_card.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);

                            filename.setText(file.getName());
                            if (file.isBookmarked()) {
                                bookmark_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_filled);
                            }
                            file_card.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), PDFViewer.class);
                                i.putExtra("filename", file.getFile());
                                startActivity(i);
                            });
                            bookmark_img.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                                if (file.isBookmarked()) {
                                    file.isBookmarked(true);
                                    bookmark_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_filled);
                                } else {
                                    file.isBookmarked(false);
                                    bookmark_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark);
                                }
                            });

                            CardView cardView = new CardView(getContext());

                            cardView.setRadius(getPixelsFromDPs(10));
                            cardView.setCardElevation(getPixelsFromDPs(6));
                            cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                            cardView.addView(file_card);
                            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutparams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    getPixelsFromDPs(38)
                            );
                            layoutparams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                            cardView.setUseCompatPadding(true);
                            cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
                            cardView.setEnabled(true);
                            cardView.setClickable(true);

                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                files_layout.addView(cardView);
                                files_layout.invalidate();
                            });

                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

The Layout I want to include into to the LinearLayout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="38dp"
android:layout_margin="6dp"
android:background="@color/colorWhite">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_file" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/filename"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="نام فایل"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bookmark"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bookmark" />
```

The LinearLayout

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/files_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I use the same way in another fragment and it works fine but I don't know why it's not working here!
The problem is not only with card view and another layout, I even tried to add text view to it but doesn't show me any result! just an empty linear layout!

**Update**

It worked by replacing scrollView and LinearLayout with RecyclerView.

Comment: What class and method in your app contains the first block of code? When does it run?

Comment: Also, have you looked at RecyclerView? This is the preferred view to use for dynamic content.

Comment: all the code above are inside a function called loadFirstTab. and it runs after receiving category list from web service and adding them to tablayout

Comment: Depending on how many things you load into your LinearLayout, I agree with Code-Apprentice, your performance could take a huge hit. I would definitely suggest a RecyclerView for this scenario. The other problem could be that your LinearLayout has a height of "match_parent" as well, and I could be wrong, but to my knowledge that doesn't work well with ScrollView.

Comment: I suggest that you create a [mcve]. This should be a new Android Studio project that only does the things that you are asking about here. You can remove the complications for making a HTTP request and just use some static data. Simplifying your code like this will help you focus on the specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you. I change LinearLayout to RecyclerView, And ScrollView to NestedScrollView so it worked.

Comment: @SorooshTanzadeh You shouldn't need a `ScrollView` at all with `RecyclerView` since it automatically takes care of scrolling.